# Infinite listview scroll in android

Tags: android

I have a task to do in which I have to show data from a local database to custom listview whose layout includes 2 bitmap and 2 text data.

References I have tried is:
 "https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview".

But it has so much that is making me confused.

Comment: why are you using library use default listview

Comment: coz data is huge so i want to implement infinite scroll listview

Comment: lol it doesn't matter use recycler view or list view it can handle large data or even you can use pagination with it

Comment: Not a question for stackoverflow. But you can use the built in `ListView` and `BaseAdapter`. The infinite scroll listview is actually going to be leveraging the native ListView for its view recycling. Once that's solid get an sqlite library, native sql interaction in android has caveats that requires a fair amount of boilerplate

Comment: if you preload your data before you can navigate your listview, then you do not need an infinite scrolling listview.

Comment: in nut shell if I say what has to be done is creating a listview add it to your layout and then pass data to Adapter, this Adapter will pass data to Listview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.endlesslistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvTest;
    int index=0;
    ArrayList<ModelClass> model = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();
    AdapterClass adapter;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        lvTest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTest);
        insertData();
        adapter = new AdapterClass(MainActivity.this, model);
        lvTest.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvTest.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
    }

    public void insertData(){
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        model.add(new ModelClass("Data "+index, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        index = index+1;
        }
    }

    public void insertNewData(){
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        model.add(new ModelClass("Data "+index, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        index = index+1;
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

        private int visibleThreshold = 20;
        private int currentPage = 0;
        private int previousTotal = 0;
        private boolean loading = true;

        public EndlessScrollListener() {
        }
        public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
            this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    currentPage++;
                }
            }
            if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
                // but you can call any function here.
                new ShowProgress().execute();
                loading = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
    }

    class ShowProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            insertNewData();
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.endlesslistview.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**AdapterClass.java**

```
package com.example.endlesslistview;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter{   
    Context context;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
      ArrayList<ModelClass> model;

    public AdapterClass(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<ModelClass> model) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.model = model;
        context=mainActivity;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return model.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
         holder.tv.setText(model.get(position).getData());
         holder.img.setImageResource(model.get(position).getImage());         
         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+model.get(position).getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });   
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ModelClass.java**

```
package com.example.endlesslistview;

public class ModelClass {

    String data;
    int image;

    public ModelClass(String data, int image) {
        this.data = data;
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }



}
```

Comment: thnx man just 1 problem . how to stop list view from loading more items.by using this example everything is fine but listview load even after data is empty.

Comment: You can add condition like this
.
if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
                // but you can call any function here.

  (hasMoreDataAvailable){
                new ShowProgress().execute();
                loading = true;
}
            }